# any use case of declaring a List<?>

Tags: java, generics

When we declare a `List` as `List<?> list = new ArrayList<>()`, we won't be able to add anything to `list` since `?` is some unknown type, we can only read from a list of some unknown type. So is there is any chance that we need a declaration as `List<?> list = new ArrayList<>()` ?

Comment: The duplicate is not an *exact* duplicate, but you can see that it may be somewhat useful as a parameter, but you'll never **need** to use `List<?> list = new ArrayList<>();`, and you really *shouldn't* either, since it can only make it harder to write your code. You could write `List<?> list = getList();` to have content in the list, but in this case the only reason you would write so is if `getList();` returned a wildcard list, i.e. most likely was poorly designed.

Comment: When it is used as a parameter, what's the difference between `void foo(List list)` and `void foo(List<?> list)` ?

Comment: Well, `List<?>` won't give you a warning about using raw types, and of course you can't add to it.